# Cant get the child dir in django hosting (alwaysdata.com) 

Tags: python, django, templates, hosting

this is my file :

```
mysite 
   templates
       homepage.html
       accounts
           a.html
           login_view.html
```

i can get the `homepage.html` and `accounts\a.html` on   127.0.0.1:8000

but in http://zjm1126.alwaysdata.net , i can only get the `homepage.html` ,and cant get 
the `accounts\a.html` ,

this is my code :

```
return render_to_response('accounts/login_view.html')
```

and the `accounts/login_view.html` is :

```
{% include "accounts\a.html" %}
```

what can i do ,  thanks ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `accounts/a.html`?

Comment: no , `accounts\a.html` is right  , because i can get this in `127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: What OS are you on locally? Windows? And remotely? Linux?

Comment: i use windows xp , and  i think alywaysdata.com maybe Linux .